# Limit links generated by Rails scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have a Category scaffold and I want to make a taskbar that links to only some of the instances. For example I have different categories for clothing: Adult, Children, Sport, Casual, etc. And I only want my navbar to link to Adult and Children:

```
<%= link_to "Adult", category_path(???) %>
```

Comment: creating action for each category is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

In your controller's action, filter the categories you want to show. For example, to show only Adult and Children:

```
@categories_to_show = Category.where(name: ['Adult', 'Children'])
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= link_to "Adults and Children Only", category_path(@categories_to_show) %>
```

Let me know if you want this or something else! I can update the answer after hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

I would control which categories I show in the controller:

```
@categories << Category.find_by(name: "Adult")
```

In view I would do:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <%= link_to(cat.name, category_path(cat)) %> 
<% end %>
```

Then the link will go to each category, and you can use the same view code for different categories.

Please comment if anything is unclear